# Python Pandas Concat list of Dataframes With Different Columns and Same Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two or more dataframes in Pandas in a list

```
A Value1
1 ABC
2 HYT
3 IUF

A Value2
1 IJT
2 GFH
3 QER
```

When using

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis = 0)
```

And after writing to CSV, the final output is like this

```
A Value1 Value2
1 ABC
1        IJT
2 HYT
2        GFH
3 IUF
3        QER
```

But I'd like it to be like this

```
A Value1 Value2
1 ABC    IJT
2 HYT    GFH
3 IUF    QER
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to concat on axis = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Concatenating on `axis 0` (should be `axis 1`).
2. Having two copies of column 'A'. You can just single out `'Value2'` in `df2`.

So:

```
df1, df2 = dfs
pd.concat((df1, df2['Value2']), axis=1)
```

returns

```
   A Value1 Value2
0  1    ABC    IJT
1  2    HYT    GFH
2  3    IUF    QER
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the desired result using `pandas.merge` or `pandas.concat`

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], 
"Value1": ['ABC', 'HYT', 'IUF']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], 
"Value2": ['IJT', 'GFH', 'QER']})

df_merge= pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=["A"])

df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2['Value2']], axis = 1)

print(df_merge)
print(df_concat)
```

Expected Output for `pandas.merge`:

```
   A Value1 Value2
0  1    ABC    IJT
1  2    HYT    GFH
2  3    IUF    QER
```

Expected Output for `pandas.concat`:

```
   A Value1 Value2
0  1    ABC    IJT
1  2    HYT    GFH
2  3    IUF    QER
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. The benefit of this method is it works for arbitrary `lst`, provided each dataframe has column 'A'.

```
lst = [df1, df2]

df = pd.concat([i.set_index('A') for i in lst], axis=1).reset_index()

#    A Value1 Value2
# 0  1    ABC    IJT
# 1  2    HYT    GFH
# 2  3    IUF    QER
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I run this it looks like columns with matching names are repeating. For example, if there's another Value1 column in a later DataFrame then the value won't slot into it's relevant A index in the first Value1 column, rather it will make a new column called Value1.